# Using Ansible's postgresql_privs to lock down Postgres public schema

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I want to lock down the public schema in a postgres database using Ansible.
Using psql in a newly created postgres install:

```
postgres=# REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE
postgres=# REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE
```

works first time.

Using Ansible though I'm getting various errors.

```
- name: Lock down PUBLIC schema
  postgresql_privs:
      db: BOB
      schema: public
      state: absent
      privs: CREATE, USAGE
      objs: public
      role: PUBLIC
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
```

The first error complained that the database BOB didn't exist - it didn't, I hadn't created it yet - this doesn't seem to bother psql however. The *db:* parameter is mandatory with *`postgresql_privs`* so I solved that by creating BOB first.

My latest effort (the above Ansible stanza) gets me

> fatal: [hostname.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Invalid privileges specified: frozenset([' USAGE'])"}

I've went through the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/postgresql_privs_module.html) and played around with the various parameters but no luck.

Thinking that maybe *Invalid privileges specified* was something to do with the user that owns the BOB database I used the above stanza with an additional line

```
login: fred
```

(ie the user that I made the owner of database BOB) but that also didn't work:

> fatal: [hostname.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Could not connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user \"fred\"\n"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra whitespace in parameter **privs** to solve the 1st problem.
Try the following

> privs: CREATE,USAGE

To solve the second problem just specify the parameter **host** explicitly. For example:

> host: 127.0.0.1

Or fix your pg_hba.conf file.
According to the official PostgreSQL docs on auth-methods:

> **Peer Authentication**
>
> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is
>   only supported on local connections.